# How to properly know the displayed image size (width-height) on a website?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I tried to find the image max-width displayed on my website, in order to have the lowest size image possible.

First, measured it directly with Lightshot screenshot software (assuming I have the max screen size):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8imX.png)

width = 1425px

Secondly, in Chrome development tool (ctrl+shift+i) I found this by inspecting the object:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onI2m.png)

width = 1140px

I know the first method is not "good" but I was surprised to not finding approximately the same size.

What is the proper method?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [mcve]? An image with a width of 100% will have the width of its container, not its own width.

Answer (score 1):

You do this kindo of stuff with the dev tools (that's what they are there for ;) ), one more thing you can do is press on the [mouse icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDBRQ.png) you can visually see elements and click on them to see their properties.
Hope it helped, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dev tools of browser. Or you can use JavaScript.

```
<button onclick="function1()">Show Width</button>
<h1 id="id1">Height:</h1>
<h1 id="id2">Width:</h1>
<img id="id3" src="img1.jpg">

<script>
    function function1 ()
    {
        document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = "Height: " + document.getElementById("id3").height;
        document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = "Width: " + document.getElementById("id3").width;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be accepting the resolution that `Chrome development Tool` is giving to you because `dev tools` are the most approprate when it comes to gather the information about different `elements`.

If you want to find out the image `max-width` you just need to click to that `img` tag that you already did and on left panel under `style` you will see all the css that you have given to your image, including the `max-width` property.

[image]

If you want confirm that `dev tools` showing the image size is accurate or not you can use the [Visbug Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visbug/cdockenadnadldjbbgcallicgledbeoc?hl=en) that gives you information of each element without working with dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where it comes from.
In windows, by default, you have a scaling by 125% of text and interface.[image]